Universal algebra and inequality
In the context of universal algebra, a class of algebras over a common signature $\Omega$. (A set of symbols, where each symbol has an associated arity) is called a variety if it is precisely the class of algebras over that signature satisfying certain equations involving terms of the algebras. These equations are defined to simply be equality of terms, for example with the signature of groups, $\{+,0,-\}$ an equation would be
$$+(+(a,b),c) = +(a,+(b,c))$$
expressing associativity. I'm interested in considering classes of algebras where one is also allowed to have statements about terms involving inequality, for example, I would like to be able to require
$$a+a \neq -a$$
My questions are:

Is this a common generalisation of the notion of a variety?

Are there cases where inequality may be expressed using only standard equations?


To elaborate on the second question, one might try to create an equivalence relation by adding $\top$ and $\bot$ to your signature as nullary operations (constants) and then add a binary relation $eq$ and somehow try to restrict it's co-domain to only $\{\top,\bot\}$ so that it acts as an indicator for whether two elements are related. Reflexivity and symmetry of the associated relation can then be described as
$$eq(x,x) =\top$$
$$eq(x,y) = eq(y,x) $$
But transitivity is not obvious, since we aren't allowed implication. The restriction of the co-domain seems like a very strong condition at first, but if you consider the class of algebras over the signature $\{eq, \top,\bot\}$ where the co-domain of $eq$ is $\{\top,\bot\}$ then this class is closed under sub-algebras (since $eq$ in the sub-algbra is just a restriction), under surjective homomorphisms, since $$eq(f(x),f(y)) = f(eq(x,y)) \in\{\top,\bot\}$$
and products, hence by Birkhoff's theorem they form a variety. Does this approach lead anywhere? Any comments or references would be appreciated. .

Hello. I'm not an expert in universal algebra, but I don't see why your class is closed under products. Won't the $\mathit{eq}$ function on $A \times B$ have codomain ${\top, \bot}^2$? I think the answer to question 2 (assuming "standard equations" means "an algebraic theory" and "can be expressed" means "is entailed by that theory") is no, because the zero algebra belongs to any variety, but cannot model any un-equality.

@IzaakvanDongen you are right, I didn't think it through properly. What is the zero algebra?

The zero algebra is the unique $\Omega$-structure that has one element. This structure automatically obeys all equations, so it is a member of every variety over $\Omega$. (Some examples in nature are the trivial group, the trivial ring, the zero $K$-vector space, the zero $R$-module, etc)
